# Intersection of sets

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A_n$ be the set of points $(x, y)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ lying on the curve $y = \frac{1}{x^n}$, $0 < x < ∞$.
What is $\bigcap_{n≥1} A_n$?

I don't have the solutions to the question. I wanted to know whether my solution is correct or not ?

The intersection should be just $(1, 1)$.

Comment: The point (1,1) -- yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(1,1)$ is evident as $1=\frac{1}{1^n}$ for all $n$. As for any other point, let $(x,y)$ be in the intersection, this means that in each $A_n$ we have that $y=\frac{1}{x^n}$, let $n<m$, we have then that $y_n<y_m$ for $0<x<1$ where $y_n=\frac{1}{x^n}$ and $y_m=\frac{1}{x^m}$, and inversely if $x$ is negative. Which means all points where $0<|x|<1$ is excluded. Now let $1<x$, we then have that $y_m<y_n$ because $\frac{1}{x^m}<\frac{1}{x^n}$, due to $x^n<x^m$, inversely so when $x$ is negative, which gives us that that the points with $0<|x|<1$ is excluded, and the points where $1<|x|$ is excluded, so only those points where $x=1$ is left and that is our only point.